# Generic function which takes parameter an array of any object

Tags: typescript

I created 2 generic functions that will take an array of any object. The first function will take property as a string and string value that you want to match to the given object. The second function will return the last `id` from the given object.

```
// First data
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Doe',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tim',
    },
];
// Second data
const data2 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'John',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Doe',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Tim',
    },
];


export const matchStr = <T>(key: string, val: string, data: Array<T>): string => {

    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        const result = data.find((obj) => {
            return obj[key] === val;
        });
        // If not undefined
        if (result) {
            return `${key} value is matched.`;
        } else {
            // Return value
            return val;
        }
    }
    return val;
};


export const getLastId = <T>(data: Array<T>): number => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        // Create an array of Id's of all items
        const idsArray: number[] = [];
        data.forEach((obj) => {
            idsArray.push(obj.id);
        });
        // Return last element id
        return idsArray[data.length - 1];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};


const resultSet1 = matchStr('name', 'John', data);
const resultSet2 = matchStr('name', 'George', data2);

console.log(resultSet1);
console.log(resultSet2);

const resultId = getLastId(data);

console.log(resultId);
```

But the following lines giving me an error:

**On first function:**

`obj[key] === val`

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.
```

**On Second function:**

`idsArray.push(obj.id)`

```
TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

**What is the problem?**
[Live link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-B1lNU5JyE05ZVl0-TrjEABxYRpjbEziC0Uj5NgHBCgJHALntJTmVUjgzPifzhEC4KLLCzNvPrczQvgHsUjbeBO27LlTOSqKAvyIKQsdNKSICIA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok. You declared that function should accept type T, but TypeScript doesn't know what is this T type. And of course it can't expect that this T will have property id.

To fix this you may do next:

- Create interface:

```js
interface IId {
    id: number;
}
```

- Change function declaration to instruct typescript that something with id should be used:

```js
export const getLastId = <T extends IId>(data: Array<T>): number => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        // Create an array of Id's of all items
        const idsArray: number[] = [];
        data.forEach((obj) => {
            idsArray.push(obj.id);
        });
        // Return last element id
        return idsArray[data.length - 1];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Now everything will work.

**UPD:**

Depending on the TS version error with

> return obj[key] === val;

Still may occurs. To fix this you have at least two options:

Declare one more interface:

```js
interface IIndexer {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

And redeclare function once more:

```js
export const matchStr = <T extends IId & IIndexer>(key: string, val: string, data: Array<T>): string => {
```

Or cast obj to any inside the function

```js
const result = data.find((obj: any) => obj[key] === val;);
```

Last option is simpler but it is not type safe so I would not recommend it for code should be maintainable

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how to fix the problem in the first function.

Comment: Check the update. My tsc doesn't  complained so I missed that part. Added two options to solve your issue.